# What's wrong with my SQL code? Getting an error on last line

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to create a MySQL procedure to calculate tax. However it says that I have an error on line 9 involving the ')' token. Any idea how to fix it? Error message is:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT ((pSalary - taxExempt) * taxRate) INTO taxesDue; END' at line 27
```

My code is:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE calc_state_tax(
IN pSalary DECIMAL(9,2), 
IN pStateCode VARCHAR(2), 
IN pStatus VARCHAR(6),
OUT taxesDue DECIMAL(9,2)
)

BEGIN
  DECLARE taxRate DECIMAL(7,5);
  DECLARE taxExempt DECIMAL(9,2);

SELECT 
    s1.taxRate, 
    s1.exemptperfiler 
    INTO taxRate,taxExempt
FROM statetax s1
WHERE s1.statecode =  CONCAT("'",pStateCode ,"'")
    AND s1.type =  CONCAT("'",pStatus,"'")
    AND s1.bracket = ( 
        SELECT MAX( s2.bracket ) 
        FROM statetax s2
        WHERE s1.statecode = s2.statecode
        AND s1.type = s2.type
        AND s2.bracket < pSalary )


  SELECT ((pSalary - taxExempt) * taxRate) INTO taxesDue;

END; //
DELIMITER;
```

Comment: You're missing a semicolon after `AND s2.bracket < pSalary )`

Comment: Oh wow. knew it was gunna be something stupid.

Comment: Ahh, @angelcool-net. We were answering this simultaneously ;-) Didn't see your comment here until I had posted.

Comment: Wait.  the extra ")" is there

Comment: Thanks.  You are correct on the );

Comment: @user1093111 It would be nice if you accept the answer :)

Comment: @angelcool.net sorry thought i did! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As my comment stated:

You're missing a semicolon after `AND s2.bracket < pSalary )`

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is a missing semicolon on the immediately preceding line; it should look like so:

> AND s2.bracket < pSalary );

See if that helps. Cheers!